# Can't find log out button for Gmail on iPhone

Tags: iphone, gmail

I am unable to log out of my Gmail account from my iPhone 6+. My screen starts from Inbox till end of folders but no log out shown. How do I log out?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Do you mind explaining a little bit more about your problem?

Comment: Log out from application, or web gmail through browser?

Answer (score 2):

Logging out needs to be done in Settings:

- open Settings
- scroll down to Accounts & Passwords, tap on it
- tap on your Gmail account
- delete it from there

This will just remove your mails and account info *from your phone*, it will not delete the account as such.

Answer (score 0):

To log out of the Gmail app,

1. tap the menu button at the top right,
2. tap your account name at the top (where your email address is),
3. choose **Manage accounts**,
4. tap **Edit** at the top-right,
5. for the account you wish to remove, choose **Remove**.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to GRG's response:

1. Click on your Profile Image in the upper right corner.
2. Click the "Manage accounts on this device" option, which is at the bottom of
    the next screen . 
    (NOT the 'Manage your Google Account" link, which comes up first).
3. Click the Toggle Button -- That's the "logout" button that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To log out, look at the letter on your far right it should be in a circle.  Click on that, then select manage accounts for this device.  On the following page, turn the toggle switch to off.   Finally, Select done in the upper left-hand corner.  You should now be logged off  phone.